# Packing files on nuget

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to package in a nuget a folder and files structure so they will be copied to the target project. That is, only content. I want all these files and folders to be copied when the nuget is installed.

This is my nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>MVCViewProvider</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>M</authors>
    <owners>M</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Test Package</description>
    <releaseNotes>Test Package</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Controllers\**\*.*" target="Content\Controllers" />
    <file src="Views\**\*.*" target="Content\Views" />
  </files>
</package>
```

When I execute this command in PowerShell:

```
nuget pack MVCViewProvider.nuspec
```

I get a package with this content:

[image]

My folders are Views and Controllers. The problem is that when I add the nuget to other project nothing is created.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The source files would need to be added to a target folder of 'Content'. Also note that this will only work for projects that use a packages.config file - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

Comment: I've created a 'Content' folder and didn't work. My target projects doesn't use packages.config. They use PackageReference in csproj. Can't I add files to my source code if I don't work with packages.config file? I edited my nuspec xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

The package needs to be changed to use [contentFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files). That because NuGet packages that work with `Packages.config`, don't always work in transitive NuGet environments (projects using `Project.json` or `PackageReferences`). Packages that work in transitive NuGet environments must use "`contentFiles`" instead of "`content`".

For example, I have created a `contentFiles` folder, which including sub folder `any\any\Controllers` and `any\any\Views`. Add `Test.cs` in the folder `Controllers` and add `Test.cshtml` in the `Views` folder:

[image]

Then create a `.nuspec` under the folder `TestNuGetSample` where the `contentFiles` folder is located:

[image]

Following is my `.nuspec` scripts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyTestCore</id>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <authors>TestContentFile</authors>
    <owners>TestContentFile</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/Views/Test.cshtml" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="false"/>
      <files include="any/any/Controllers/Test.cs" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="false"/>
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="contentFiles/any/any/Views/Test.cshtml" target="contentFiles/any/any/Views/Test.cshtml" />
    <file src="contentFiles/any/any/Controllers/Test.cs" target="contentFiles/any/any/Controllers/Test.cs" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then pack this `.nupsec` file to nuget package, and set it to the nuget local repository.

Create a new test project ASP.NET Core MVC project with PackageReference in csproj, then install that nuget package, Test.cs and Test.cshtml will be added to the new project:

[image]

Hope this helps.