# Is there any Roslyn Analyzer equivalent for javascript in Visual studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, nuget, roslyn

We can create a custom analyzer using Roslyn in C#, using which we can create a NuGet package and add it to our project.
Now I have a problem that my project contains javascript files and I want to analyze those too. Hence I need Roslyn equivalent for javascript using which we can create a NuGet package and add it to our project.
Any idea how i can achieve this?
I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: This also looks useful [Packing static content in Nuget for PackageReferece projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751019/packing-static-content-in-nuget-for-packagereferece-projects)

Comment: Not true, the question is about JS analyzer, not packaging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Roslyn compiler technology is only used on the C# and Visual Basic compilers, and I wouldn't recommend using NuGet for that, anyway.

You should be looking at [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint)) or [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint)) and use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) for packaging it.

Comment: FYI, it i possible to put js libraries into Nuget (e.g. [jquery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/3.5.0.1))

Comment: This seems like a [very strange edit to make](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61466793/2). You shouldn't edit tags to fit your answer. The OP is not asking about npm